# Lombok's `@Builder` annotation stubbornly stays package - private

Tags: java, intellij-idea, builder, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have the following `@Builder` - annotated class:

```java
@Data
@Builder(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@Entity
public class LiteProduct
{
    // Minimal information required by our application.
    @Id
    private Long id;    // Unique
    private String name;
    private Long costInCents;
    private String type;

     // Model the product types as a Hash Set in case we end up with several
     // and need fast retrieval.
    public final static Set<String> PRODUCT_TYPES = new HashSet<>
             (Arrays.asList("flower", "topical", "vaporizer", "edible", "pet"));

    // Have to allow creation of products without args for Entities.
    public LiteProduct()
    {

    }

    public LiteProduct(@NonNull final Long id, @NonNull final String name,
                       @NonNull final String type, @NonNull final Long costInCents)
    {
        if(!PRODUCT_TYPES.contains(type))
        {
            throw new InvalidProductTypeException(type);
        }
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.costInCents = costInCents;
    }
```

Whenever I want to use the builder class that `Lombok` is purported to give me, despite the fact that the IDE seems to detect it just fine:

[image: IDE detects inner builder class]

I get a compile-time error about its visibility:

[image: Builder class not publically available]

I have looked at some workarounds such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48318097/is-it-possible-to-make-lomboks-builder-public) or [this](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder), and they all seem to imply that my problem ought to already be solved automatically and that `Lombok` by default produces `public` Builder classes. This does not seem to be implied from my output, and does not happen even after I put the parameter `access=AccessLevel.PUBLIC` in my `@Builder` annotation in `LiteProduct`. Any ideas? Is there something wrong with the fact that this class is also an `@Entity`? Something else I'm not detecting?

// Edit: I determined that when I move the class in the same package as the one I am calling the builder pattern from, it works just fine. This is *not* an `@Entity` issue, but a package visibility issue which based on what I'm reading should *not* be there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the following line of code to create an instance of `LiteProduct`:

```
return new LiteProduct.builder().build();
```

instead of:

```
return LiteProduct.builder().build();
```

which is what the `@Builder` annotation allows you to do. Clearly `builder()` is like a factory method for `Builder`s that already calls `new` for you.